# Electorate Badge

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

According to the Badges page, the Electorate Badge is awarded when:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

According to my stats I've voted 1379 times, 985 (71%) on answers and 394 (29%) on questions... but I don't have the badge. What am I missing?

Comment: 394 < 600, so no, you don't yet qualify.

Answer (score 17):

You're misinterpreting the badge description. You need to:

- Vote on 600 questions (not answers).
- Have at least 25% of your total votes be on questions.

Comment: Ah! My bad. I was reading "Questions" to mean everything -- ie, making the distinction between voting on several different pages.

Comment: Then what does 25% of your votes on questions mean? 100% of the votes should be on questions obviously.(All 600 votes)

Comment: @Auser 25% of total votes (votes on Q and A). Say you have voted on 600 questions and 2400 answers. So your total votes are 3000, and 20% of them are on questions.